# I am getting multiple instances of setInterval, when i run same function multiple time?

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

```js
  
let output = document.getElementById('output');
function startGame(){
  let timerStart = 6;
  let countdown = setInterval(() => {
    timerStart--;
    if(timerStart === 0){
      clearInterval(countdown);
    }
    console.log(timerStart);
    output.innerHTML = timerStart;
    timer.innerHTML = timerStart;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="startGame()">Start Game</button>
          
<p id='output'>output here</p>
```

***Problem***

When i click start game once it works just fine.
**output: 5, 4,3,2,1**
But when i click start game more then once, I get more then one timer running too
like 
**output: 5, 4, 5,3, 4, 2, 3, 1, 2..etc**
Help me please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interval ID should be *persistent* (in the outer scope), so that on a subsequent call of `startGame`, you can call `clearInterval` with it before going onto the rest of the code:

```
let output = document.getElementById('output');
let intervalId;
function startGame(){
  // Clear the past interval, if there is one:
  clearInterval(intervalId);

  let timerStart = 6;
  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    timerStart--;
    if(timerStart === 0){
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
    console.log(timerStart);
    output.innerHTML = timerStart;
    timer.innerHTML = timerStart;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to clear the interval at the begining of the `startGame` function :

```
const output = document.getElementById('output');
let intervalId;    

function displayCounter(counter) {
  output.innerHTML = counter;
  timer.innerHTML = counter;
}

function startGame(){
  clearInterval(intervalId);
  let counter = 5;
  displayCounter(counter);

  intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if(--counter === 0){
      clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
    console.log(counter);
    displayCounter(counter);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Another solution is to prevent the user to recreate multiple intervals

```
function startGame(){
  if(intervalId) {
    return;
  }

  let counter = 5;
  displayCounter(counter);
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remember the previously started interval and then stopping it if it is already running like so

```
let countdown = null;
let output = document.getElementById('output');
function startGame(){
  let timerStart = 6;
  if (countdown) clearInterval(countdown);
  countdown = setInterval(() => {
    timerStart--;
    if(timerStart === 0){
      clearInterval(countdown);
    }
    console.log(timerStart);
    output.innerHTML = timerStart;
    timer.innerHTML = timerStart;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because your not storing the value of countdown anywhere, the system requires a reference to the interval to clear it. outside of your function you should keep a list (or something) which contains each countdown variable

Comment: How can i store countdown?

Comment: val intervalArray = new Array()

then later in the code

intervalArray.push(countdown)

this should allow you to maintain as many references to countdown as you like. However I think in your case it may be simpler to just disable the start game button until the timer is complete (when timerstart === 0 )

Answer (score 0):

The truly problem is what you wish happen when you click the button more than once.
If you want do nothing when click the button second time after the game was started.
Maybe you do some change like these.

```
let output = document.getElementById('output');
let started=false;
function startGame(){
if(started)return;
  let timerStart = 6;
  let countdown = setInterval(() => {
    timerStart--;
    if(timerStart === 0){
      clearInterval(countdown);
started=false;
    }
    console.log(timerStart);
    output.innerHTML = timerStart;
    timer.innerHTML = timerStart;
  }, 1000);
started=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the timer has been started already, if it is do not run the function. This can be done by using the `countdown` variable which will hold the timer id. If the id is populated then do not run the function again unless it reaches 0 and is cleared:

```js
const startGame = (function(){
    let countdown = null;
    let output = document.getElementById('output');
    function startGame(){
      let timerStart = 6;
      if(countdown){ return; }
      countdown = setInterval(() => {
          timerStart--;
          if(timerStart === 0){
            clearInterval(countdown);
            countdown = null;
          }
          output.innerHTML = timerStart;
      }, 1000);
    }
    return startGame;
})();
```

```html
<button onclick="startGame()">Start Game</button>
          
<p id='output'>output here</p>
```